# AppDelegate not finding declared and synthesized property of ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, properties, uiapplicationdelegate

My app has been under dev for a few months and am now being asked to add Core Data. SMH. It is  a tabViewController app. I don't know if that helps with the answer.

So here I am trying to add it and i'm getting errors. I build for Core Data in the **AppDelegate.h**, so I have created these IVARs and build them appropriately later in the .m.

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

In the viewControllers that need CoreData interaction, I have given them (in the .h files):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

and synthesized them in the .m:

```
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
```

Now, back to the **AppDelegate**. In the .m, when I try to pass the pointer for the managedObjectContext from the delegate to the views (like so):

```
viewController1.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
viewController2.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

I am getting an XCode Error that reads (for both viewController1 and 2):

```
Property 'managedObjectContext' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'
```

I don't understand this because the property in both View Controllers clearly exists and is synthesized.

I've even tried quitting and restarting XCode. Maybe a system reboot? <-- Is that absurd??

(I know I have added more than you may need..) Any help?

Comment: Is the controller header file properly #import'ed ?

Comment: Yes, the app has been under dev for a few months, uses the same ViewControllers and builds and runs well (except for setting the properties).

Comment: I would ask first why you are trying to set properties that may or may not be `readonly` first...

Comment: To incorporate CoreData, I created a new project using CoreData and looked to see what was created. I figured this way was the safest way to add CoreData to my project since it is an Apple default. They are not readonly.

Comment: Can you build through these errors, or not?

Comment: no, they are errors not warnings. I can build through if I comment those two lines out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I found this answer on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345506/unable-to-pass-nsmanagedobjectcontext-to-my-view-controller):*

"An alternative approach is to pull the context from your app delegate - at the moment the app delegate has to be re-coded if you change the way your app is organised. You can get a pointer to the app delegate anywhere, so the following piece of code can be added to any view controller:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  
self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
```

Usually in the viewDidLoad."

*Thank you to user: [jrturton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/852828/jrturton) for the answer*

Answer (score 0):

First, it's easier to use UIManagedDocument to set up core data if the app has already been created `without` CoreData.

So I would do this first in AppDelegate. See the UIManagedDocument class reference over at the apple developer website as well as my answer here for help:

[Objective c - Core Data saving approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887437/objective-c-core-data-saving-approach/10887737#10887737)

Second your appDelegate should be aware of your initial view controller which is actually your `UITabBarController`, and your tab bar controller is aware of its first view controller which should be the target for your context and therefore needs an `NSManagedObejectContext` property in the public API.

So I forget the exact code but it's something like:

```
// in appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions or somewhere
UITabBarController* tabBarController = self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController* viewController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[your first controller]];

// Pass your context
viewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

// Be sure to #import your first viewControllers API so that propert is visible.
// That may have been your initial problem.
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: With or without UIManagedDocument, the code below still does not work. It seems as if I can't even make a public method to set it either. I'll re-confirm your answer if you can offer a better solution! Thanks in advance